# Docker image for python3.5 and ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker

I am trying to create a docker image for python 3.5 and Ubuntu 16.04.

I have created the docker file but at the time of requirement installation using pip the package "psycopg2" is giving the error.

`psycopg2` needs Postgres installed in.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# bring system up-to-date
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get upgrade -qqy


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip python3.6-venv
RUN apt-get install -y git

# update pip
RUN python3.6 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3.6 -m pip install wheel

RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN apt-get install bzip2


RUN rm -rf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --force-yes gettext libgettextpo-dev fontconfig

# install phantom js
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share && \
  cd /usr/share \
  && wget -O phantomjs.tar.bz2 https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 && tar xvfj phantomjs.tar.bz2  && mv phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 phantomjs && rm -rf phantomjs.tar.bz2


RUN echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y  ttf-mscorefonts-installer



COPY ./helvetica /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts

RUN fc-cache -f -v

RUN fc-list | grep -i 'helvetica'




# Requirements have to be pulled and installed here, otherwise caching won't work
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements/local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

COPY ./compose/local/django/start.sh /start.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start.sh /start-celeryworker.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-celeryworker.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker.sh

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start.sh /start-celerybeat.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-celerybeat.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat.sh

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Is there an available docker image for ubuntu 16.04 and python3.5?

Comment: The "stretch" and "jessie" flavors of the [standard `python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) are based on Debian releases which should be "close enough" for most purposes, since Ubuntu is mostly Debian with more of a desktop focus and a much faster release schedule.

Comment: David, is there ready docker image available for python3.5 and Ubuntu 16.04?
I have my own reasons for going with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you solved ? I have similar problems on trying to create an Image from a Dockerfile that is for Ubuntu 16.04 and with Django